# Is it possible to - on:hover pause css3 animation and change its background color?

Tags: css, animation, colors, hover, css-animations

I'm using keyframes to constantly change the font-color of an `<a>` link. On `:hover` I want to be able to stop the animation and define the font-color .

```
@-webkit-keyframes fontt {
  0%, 100% {font-size:50px;color:black;}      
  50% {color:red;}}
#box a {-webkit-animation: fontt 2s infinite;}
#box a:hover {color:#4480e8;-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Is it possible to pause the keyframes and also change the font color?

I tried using `!important`,

I tried putting the `color:red;` on different naming conventions (`a:hover`, `#box a:hover`, `#box:hover a`

Will having paused keyframes override my `:hover`? Is there a way to set priority?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/rvBS2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rules set by the keyframe seem to have higher importance in the cascade.  I'm not sure if this should be the case, but [`@media` rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade) have the highest level of importance.  `@keyframes` either should too or this is a bug.  The cascade spec does not mention them specifically.

Instead of using `pause`, you can remove the animation entirely.

```
#box a:hover {-webkit-animation: none;color:red; font-size: 50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvBS2/1/

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. If I wanted to make it have a different animation on `:hover`, could I just add something like 


`@-webkit-keyframes font2 {
  0%, 100% {font-size:50px;
    color:red;}
  50% {color:black;}
}`  and `#box a:hover {-webkit-animation: fonti;font-size:50px;}`

Comment: @user2118228 probably; you can try it in the jsfiddle

Comment: it doesn't seem to do it. Could it be an issue with a psuedo class activating an animation??

Comment: hmm i tried it twice to no avail. Must have been a syntax error. Thanks so much for your help, sir. May your explosions be explodeful!!! This case is closed!

Comment: Upvoted this for stating clearly the higher keyframe importance. Explains the problems I have with one of my animations using also a hover on the element (that triggered the keyframes) do not respect the smooth transition of the hover any longer.

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-animation-play-state: paused` and `-webkit-animation-play-state: running`